# cant invalidate nstimer in another class

Tags: objective-c

I cant invalidate a NSTimer, he is continue to run.

in **class A** i have :

```
-(void)startMachine
{
    NSLog(@"START THE MACHINE " );
    doesOn=1;
      machineClock=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(recordMachine:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
 ....//machineClock is on the .h file in interface
}

-(void)recordMachine:(NSTimer*)timer
{

    NSLog(@"recordMachine");
...

-(void)stopMachine
{

         NSLog(@"STOP THE MACHINE !! " );
         [machineClock invalidate];
         machineClock=nil;
...
}
```

then in **class b**, to start and stop it with :

```
   classAinst=[recordMachine alloc];
    [classAinst startMachine]; //it starts here.
    ......
   [classAinst stopMachine]; //it class the method to stop it,but the timer still ticks.
```

what may cause this ?
do i need to create a property to the timer ?
class a is holding the timer from b, so it should stop it no ?

Comment: Are you sure you're starting it only once?

Comment: yes i am sure,have checked that .

Comment: @user1280535 just for clarification, when you stop your recordMachine, "STOP THE MACHINE" is printed, but the "recordMachine" is still printing, right?

Comment: yes exactly . thats why i think i lost the timer instance or something..dont know.

Answer (score 0):

classB.h

```
@interface classB : ParentClass
@property(nonatomic, strong)ClassA *Aclass;
@end
```

classB.m

```
 @implementation classB
 @synthesize Aclass;
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Aclass =[[ClassA alloc]init];
    [Aclass startMachine];
    [Aclass stopMachine];
}
 @end
```

you lost the instance of classA, thats why you also lost the control of it. try the code above.

Comment: i get errors with that, for example: that i Aclass is not in interface, then i added it, and it gives errors about the "strong" property..

Comment: my naming in the sample code are just for sample purpose. use your classes name

Comment: i have fix it. i couldnt use the strong, because i dont use complier with ARC. but it didnt solve my problem. as i wrote here above,  i can see that at the start of classB, the main class, i load into cache many images, then i have seen that if i dont load them- it somehow stop the timer ! that means the class b that calls the timer,takes lots of memory and lost the instance of B

Answer (score 0):

Stopping the timer from different thread that started it will cause this.

If you are not using multiple threads, you're most probably stopping the wrong timer or the timer of the wrong object. You can debug this if whenever starting a timer, you'd print addresses of it and the object that is starting it:

```
NSLog(@"starting %@ owned by %@", timer, self);
```

And the same when stopping:

```
NSLog(@"stopping %@ owned by %@", timer, self);
```

Then make sure numbers match. (And numbers in `ProcessName[11337:707]` part of NSLog's output must match too: the second is thread ID and if it differs, it means you do stop timer from other thread).

Comment: i got something ! i can see that at the start of classB, the main class, i load into cache many images, then i have seen that if i dont load them- it somehow stop the timer ! that means the class b that calls the timer,takes lots of memory and lost the instance of B ..